# 403 permission denied when invoking Google App Engine Admin API from Google Cloud Scheduler

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use the Google App Engine Admin API to patch my GAE service servingStatus from a Google Cloud Scheduler job.

My service is a nodejs12 standard environment manually scaled single instance default service.

**My job is config is:**

**Target:** HTTP

**URL:** [https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/{MY_PROJECT_ID}/services/default/versions/{MY_VERSION_ID}](https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/%7BMY_PROJECT_ID%7D/services/default/versions/%7BMY_VERSION_ID%7D)

**Auth header:** "Add OAuth token"

**Service account:** my app engine default service account [PROJECT_NAME]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

**Scope:** https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

When I run the job, I get a 403 PERMISSION_DENIED error.

I've granted my app engine default service account a variety of roles to try and get round this, including:

- App Engine Admin
- App Engine Standard Environment Service Agent
- Cloud Functions Invoker
- Owner
- OAuth Config Viewer

I've also tried disabling and re-enabling the Cloud Scheduler API.

But nothing is working and I'm running out of options here.

Anyone got any ideas? Do I need to use a different service account apart from my GAE default service account? Are there any other roles that need to be brought into the mix? Do I need to amend the privileges of the Cloud Scheduler service account?

I note that when I try to invoke the same URL from the OAuth2 playground I get the same error despite exchanging authorisation tokens, which leads me to suspect it is something to do with roles assigned to the app engine default service account.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the permissions issue, I found it necessary to encapsulate the App Engine Admin API invocation inside a Cloud Function, which is invoked by the Cloud Scheduler job.

This allows the default service account permissions to be used in a way that (apparently) cannot be done via direct Cloud Scheduler invocation.

Example nodejs implementation is contained in the following blog post (thank you, CorePox):

https://corepox.net/devlog/reduce-google-app-engine-flex-costs-with-cloud-scheduler-cloud-functions-and-the-gae-admin-api